# Exporting a Layer as a Shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I'm having trouble figuring out how to export my project as a shapefile. All the instructions I have looked at before says export as an ESRI Shapefile but I can not find where that is. [image] This is my screen, I go to save as on my layer and I get a list of formats but it doesn't seem like any are what I'm looking for. Is there anyway to export this location as a shapefile with coordinates?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Shapefile is a 25-year old vector format that supports only one table (and not very well). It doesn't make sense to export a *project* as shapefile, especially for datatypes that it cannot support (raster).

Comment: That's a raster file, shapefiles are vector files